# Alfresco :: few PHP APIs is working only

Tags: php, alfresco

I am trying to use alfresco. I want to use PHP restfull APIs.

```
Followings are my task.
1) Listing of all directory and documents.
2) Upload a file and create or add properties/metadata for the file.
3) Checkout and checkin a file.
4) Retrieve a specific version of a file. 
5) Create and edit tag.
```

I got list of APIs from.

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/uri/
and 
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/2.1_REST_API
```

Some of them is working and some of them is not working. Can anyone provide me the restfull PHP APIs for above tasks.

Even I am getting internal server error. Below is the code to add/create a tag.

```
<form       
action="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/b0697dd1-
ae94-4bf6-81c8-5e2fa098ddfa/tags" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="name" value='["t222a","t222b","t222c"]' />
<input type="text" name="tags" value='["t222a","t222b","t222c"]' />     
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Also there is no such help how I use custom data using API call.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case sounds like a typically usecase for CMIS. Take a look at the [Apache Chemistry CMIS PHP Client](http://chemistry.apache.org/php/phpclient.html)

If you want to use Alfresco's REST API Assuming that you're using Alfresco 4.2 then take a looks at the offical [REST API](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/references/RESTful-intro.html) docs.

as most REST APIs most of Alfresco's Webscripts expects a json payload and not a FormData.
The following curl is an example to add a tag (basis auth with admin/admin):

```
curl "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/4c3aa00e-2aee-440e-aab5-0bb0570d8b01/tags" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" --data-binary "[""tag1"", ""tag2""]"
```

If you want to POST this via browser the you'll have to build the XHR-request on your own, e.g. by using jquery:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/4c3aa00e-2aee-440e-aab5-0bb0570d8b01/tags",
            data: JSON.stringify(["tag3", "tag4"]),
            success: function() {},
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am not talking about Alfresco PHP SDK. I want to use the above tasks by alfresco rest APIs on my website based on PHP.

Comment: Yes I am using....
Alfresco Community v4.2.0
(r63893-b12) schema 6033
Spring Surf and Spring WebScripts - v1.2.0
..........................................

Comment: I already looked on REST API docs. I am really very annoyed on alfresco CMIS. There is no such good tutorial over internet. There is no such simple steps to implement rest APIs. Integrating alfresco apis is not so easy. Codes are not tested yet properly. No such proper guideline to use APIs. I seen they are using store_type, store_id, nodeRef as the parameter for the APIs. I did not found any quick help for it. Disgusting...

Comment: store_type, store_id, nodeRef: {store_type://store_id/uid} == nodeRef
did you take a look at Jeffs tutorials: http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series
There is also a comprehensive book about CMIS & Alfresco: http://www.packtpub.com/learn-everything-to-start-coding-integrations-with-content-management-server/book

Comment: That means, before implementing Alfresco rest APIs, I have to go through the huge tutorials. But in the practical case, no client will provide the huge time to learn. As a developer I need only few steps and examples to implement it. Before learning the car driving if one tells you to learn mechanism how to build a car. Is that make sense? I simply need examples to implement of rest APIs.

Comment: well, Alfresco is Open Source - The whole Share client uses Alfresco's REST capabilities, take a look & stop flaming here.
As said before: Go ahead with CMIS - it is worth to learn

Comment: I am not happy as because the below code is not working and nobody is giving me the solution.
 ----------------------
Even I am getting internal server error. Below is the code to add/create a tag.

<form       
action="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/b0697dd1-
ae94-4bf6-81c8-5e2fa098ddfa/tags" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="name" value='["t222a","t222b","t222c"]' />
<input type="text" name="tags" value='["t222a","t222b","t222c"]' />     
<input type="submit" />
</form>

Comment: Thank you so much. The above browser API code is working fine.

Comment: Plesae look at another problem.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278216/alfresco-how-to-add-custom-properties-during-file-upload-using-rest-api

Waiting for your kind help.