# Alfresco:: How to add custom properties during file upload using REST api

Tags: php, alfresco

While uploading a file, I am using the below API.

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload
```

File is getting uploaded successfully in alfresco repository. 
Now my requirement is, If I want to add custom properties like 
**custom1, custom2, custom3, custom4** etc
Could you please give us a solution using browser API/AJAX call.

Below is my code

```
<form method="post" name="uploadForm" enctype='multipart/form-data' id="upload_form" action="http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload">
   <input type="hidden" name="destination" id="destination" value="workspace://SpacesStore/3f132339-bac1-4e0c-be03-b2ec5dbea61b" />
   <input type="hidden" name="overwrite" id="overwrite" value="false" />   
   <br />
   <label>custom1:</label>
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="custom1" id="custom1" />
   <br />
   <label>custom2:</label>
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="custom2" id="custom2" />
   <br />
   <label>custom3:</label>
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="custom3" id="custom3" />
   <br />           
   <label>custom4:</label>
   <br />
   <input type="text" name="custom4" id="custom4" />
       <br />
       <br />
   <label>File:</label>
   <br />
   <input class="button" type="file" name="filedata" id="filedata" />
   <br />
   <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Will these properties be in the Alfresco model? You cannot upload arbitrary properties to Alfresco.

Comment: I don't know what to do. But my basic requirement was that. 
If it is possible using by alfresco data model, could you please explain how I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html) on custom content properties so that you can understand how to define your properties in the content model.

Then you can use the Alfresco REST API, or preferably, the CMIS API to update the properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need solution using REST APIs. Could you please provide me simple steps to get this done.

Comment: I read the above tutorial link. Its very good. 
But it says to register the new model with a spring bean. But I am a PHP developer, looking for a Restfull API to get it done. Could you provide me it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to copy what is in the sample source code and adjust it for your needs. It is only XML.